# How to show selected part of website to iframe?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe, widget

I want to show this part from this [website](https://www.betrush.com/verified/) into iframe but have a issues with it. I used this code to get it:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 575px;">
<iframe scrolling="no" src="https://www.betrush.com/verified/" 
style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -96px; height: 1200px; margin-top: 
-486px; width: 650px;">
</iframe>
</div>
```

So my question is how to modify my iframe settings to get this part of that website.

[image]

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.betrush.com/verified/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Utilise a BetRush API to extract just a segment of their page data. This is by far the easier and more preferable option.
2. Assuming they don't have an API, your only alternative is to load the **entire** website, and then use JavaScript to extract the segments that you wish to display:

```js
function loadDoc(target) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;

      var doc = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document;
      doc.open();
      doc.write(this.responseText);
      doc.close();

    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", target, true);
  xhttp.send();
}

loadDoc("http://www.example.com");
```

```html
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
```

The content is saved as `this.reponseText`. You'll need to extract data from that based on what you get returned from the website, and then write that to the `<iframe>` with `doc.write();`.

Having said that, the target **also** needs to allow scraping. Unfortunately, it would seem as though BetRush has **[Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin)** disabled, meaning that you cannot scrape their site. Therefore, you cannot load part of their website in this way.

Considering BetRush doesn't appear to have an API, and don't allow you to scrape their website, you cannot extract part of their site for inclusion within an iframe.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: how to do that? can you help me with that JS? i only need to show that part of website to my site, nothing more. is possible that via iframe?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.betrush.com/verified/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Im not trying to get data. SImply to show some selected part from that website to iframe on my site.

Comment: @DrMTR -- That 'part' of their website is technically their 'data'. Unfortunately, without an API or them allowing you to access their data, you cannot include part of their website in an iframe.

Comment: With inserting code from first post i can show some part of their site, but not exaclty that i need.. Its showing left side from website. i need right side with table.